# How to convert NSMutableArray value to NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have NSMutableArray named *total and `UILabel` as *lblTotal. I got result value from looping. Now I want to set this value as `UILabel` in `viewDidLoad`. How can I fix this?

Here is code I am using.

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < [node childCount]; counter++) {
            if ([[[node childAtIndex:counter] name] isEqualToString:@"Total"]){

                NSString *str = [[node childAtIndex:counter] stringValue];

                [total addObject:str];
                NSLog(@"Grand total is %@", total);
            }
        }
```

Simply I want to set result value in NSString lbltotal.text = total.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSArray  *array1 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
NSString *joinedString = [array1 componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

[`componentsJoinedByString:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/componentsJoinedByString%3a) will join the components in the array by the specified string and return a string representation of the array.

**To set the value on UILabel**

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[label setText:joinedString];
```

Comment: I got result "1100". Now I want to set this NSMutableArray result value into UILabel in another method.

Comment: Just pass the value to that method as NSString and set it on the UILabel

Answer (score 2):

To convert an NSMutableArray to NSString it's like this:

```
NSMutableArray * myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
NSString * myString = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
UILabel * myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[myLabel setText:myString];
```

I hope it helps ;-)